# Leading White Space when importing CRM Data

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have updated Contact Entity field using Excel import.Fieldname:FieldA which is a text box. The import was "Successful" ,except I find the leading white space in FieldA now and I am not able to even delete them manually.

I tried to export them and used the trim function in Excel and reimported them but it still comes up with a leading whitespace. (There are approx. 100 records)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, CRM doesn't recognize removing space as a change.

I have used two step workaround for this:

- modify field by removing space and adding . (dot) at the beginning of
  the field
- import
- remove . (dot)
- import

it's bit messy but worked for me.